# Always Pass Post variable in $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have about 70 of these in my angularjs code. About 65 of them send the authtoken variable through.

```
$http.post("/url", { name: $scope.name, authtoken:localStorage['authtoken']});
```

I remember seeing somewhere that it might be beneficial to make it so it passes authtoken as a default through all my `$http.post` calls so I don't have to type it in every time.

Is this a good idea? If so, does anyone know how I would accomplish it? Just looking for some insight and getting pushed in the right direction.

Comment: do a search for *"angular httpInterceptor"*. first link will likely be $http docs and then lots of tutorials

Comment: Please limit your questions to those which do not solicit opinions, which is specifically off-topic according to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Opinion aside, it's a pretty damn interesting question that would help a lot of people since I couldn't find it in the search @MikeMcCaughan which also feels like a good opportunity to learn best practices in regards to limiting the amount of code someone has to write. But sure, i'll limit my questions next time I appreciate your insight, glad you were #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Interceptors` like this:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
      request: function(req) {
        if(req.method.toUpperCase() === 'POST') {
            if(typeof req.data === 'object') {
                req.data = req.data || {};// typeof Null is 'object' since the beginning of JavaScript
                req.data['authtoken'] = localStorage['authtoken'];
            } else {
                req.data += '&authtoken='+localStorage['authtoken']
            }
        }
        return req;
      }
    };
  }
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use of `jQuery.ajaxSetup()`
 here is API https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

You can set up ajax global handler `ajaxStar` (https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

and modify the passed data by adding your authtoken.
Here is good article nearly about http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/simplify-your-ajax-code-by-using-jquery-global-ajax-handlers-and-ajaxsetup-low-level-interface

Comment: Thanks Yan, but I am using angular and not jquery